# Cucumber-rails on jruby installs gem into my apps root directory with bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, cucumber, jrubyonrails

Just installed `cucumber 0.7.2` and `cucumber-rails 0.3.1` with jruby-1.4.0 on OSX.  When I run a bundle install, it places a cucumber-rails directory in my main app with all of the gem code/dependencies.

First off, this is definitely not what I want and I'm not sure why this happens for cucumber-rails only.

Second, if I delete this folder and just manually install cucumber-rails, when I run `script/generate feature blah` I get

```
/Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:344:in `refresh!': source index not created from disk (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:34:in `refresh!'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `new'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:21:in `add_frozen_gem_path'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:298:in `add_gem_load_paths'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:132:in `process'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/Repos/app/source/trunk/config/environment.rb:13
    from /Users/bradrobertson/Repos/app/source/trunk/config/environment.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/generate.rb:1
    from /Users/bradrobertson/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.4.0/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/generate.rb:3:in `require'
    from script/generate:3
```

Similarly running `rake cucumber` I get

```
rake aborted!
source index not created from disk
```

So something obviously doesn't work.  If I add that cucumber-rails directory back in, then my `rake cucumber` actually runs.

Can someone tell me why it would need to install the gem right in my rails app?  I've never seen this before.

**setup**
jruby-1.4.0
cucumber-0.7.2
cucumber-rails 0.3.1
bundler 0.9.23
webrat 0.7.1

**EDIT**

To add to this, I decided I was sick of trying to get this to work so I removed all cucumber / cucumber-rails deps from my Gemfile and reran `bundle install`.  It still creates the cucumber-rails directory and furthermore, I can't run anything unless that directory is present, (rake etc...) otherwise I get the `source index not created from disk` message.

**EDIT2**
I just noticed that my `Rails.root/.bundle/config` has `BUNDLE_PATH: cucumber-rails`.  Does anyone have any idea why this would be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got to do with the way you are installing stuff with bundler.

you probably did something like:

bundle install cucumber-rails

If you do this bundler assumes you want to vendor your bundle
in this directory inside your project.

your .bundle/config
should probably just contain:

---

BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"

By deleting this folder you are in fact deleting your bundle.

Just change this as above, and run:

bundle install.

Comment: wow totally forgot about this question, ya you're absolutely right, i coincidentally started looking into the bundler source just the other day and realized what was going on here.  Thanks for bringing this back to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a from-scratch application running with the following gems:

```
$ jruby -S gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.5)
actionpack (2.3.5)
activerecord (2.3.5)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.6)
activeresource (2.3.5)
activesupport (2.3.5)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.25)
cucumber (0.7.2)
cucumber-rails (0.3.1)
database_cleaner (0.5.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
gherkin (1.0.24)
jdbc-sqlite3 (3.6.3.054)
jruby-openssl (0.7)
json_pure (1.4.3)
nokogiri (1.4.1)
rack (1.0.1)
rack-test (0.5.3)
rails (2.3.5)
rake (0.8.7)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
trollop (1.16.2)
webrat (0.7.1)
```

I had to upgrade to Bundler 0.9.25 and I followed the instructions here for using Bundler with Rails 2:

http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

Here's how my Gemfile looked:

```
source :gemcutter
gem "rails", "~> 2.3.5"
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter', :require => false
gem 'jdbc-sqlite3', :require => false

group :development do
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: hey sorry i haven't had time to verify this, i'll get to it when i can